# How to get all users data from firebase database in custom listview in android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I have Firebase database with childs with uid of each user and this childs contain sub-childs like username, city, etc.

I want to get all the users username and city from the Firebase database.

How can I do this?

I tried many solutions from StackOverflow and other websites but I couldn't understand it.

So, please if you are replying me then mention all the things meaning properly in the answer.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/Database.java

Comment: Yes, but i can't found answer properly so i posted this question...but now i got solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer is here, it worked for me it may work for you as well

[How to list the registered users names in Android (Firebase)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082030/how-to-list-the-registered-users-names-in-android-firebase)

Here is my code which takes out the usernames of all users registered to my app just like the people you may know stuff of facebook

```
//to fetch all the users of firebase Auth app
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    DatabaseReference usersdRef = rootRef.child("users");

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

                        Log.d("TAG", name);

                        array.add(name);

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(OtherUsersActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    usersdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

Hope this make work for you.
Declare the ArrayList globally.