# How to list data from Firebase database to listview? Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a system where I can enter a reminder into the Android app, have it sent to Firebase to be accessed to all devices with the app, and have that reminder come up on a notification. I still need to make the interface that I can send things to Firebase from the app, but I am having trouble retrieving the data. Right now it doesn't like my listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter) line because it thinks I am calling a null object reference. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");



    Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(value);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }//public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) end

        class User {

            public String username;
            public String email;

            public User() {
                // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
            }

            public User(String username, String email) {
                this.username = username;
                this.email = email;
            }

        }//class User end

        public void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
            User user = new User(name, email);
       }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}//protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) end
}
```

There are some unused classes, but my main question is, Why is the array null? And why does this crash the app when I try to run it on the emulator?

Also, the only things in my database are parent Users and its one child, "goy" (as a test child).

Comment: `it doesn't like my listView` there are multiple examples of what you are seeking

Comment: @Eminem could you give a link to one or two?

Comment: http://camposha.info/source/android-firebase-listview-saveretrieveshow

Comment: You can take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)**.