# Java Android Retrieve Pushed Key Data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on something in which I should be able to fetch children of a pushed key from Firebase. It should retrieve child record such as:

- Date
- Topic
- More Info

The each time when I save an entry, it also can be viewed in the application. The firebase tree is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8REu4.png)

The saved entry - pushed key screenshot is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLoee.png)

When you click it, this is how it is viewed by the user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCWhU.png)

The problem is, whenever the id is clicked, it just receives the last entry but not the others which is already is in the Firebase.

My code is below:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mFirebasedatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(uid).child("dailyDiary");
    id = mFirebasedatabase.getKey();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    mFirebasedatabase.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for  (DataSnapshot datasnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                UserDiary userDiary = datasnap.getValue(UserDiary.class);
                String date = userDiary.getDate_time();
                String info = userDiary.getMoreInfo();
                String topic = userDiary.getTopic();
                Log.d("TAG", date + " / " +  topic +  " / " + info);
                list.add(date + topic + info);
            }
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_diary);
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeThreeViewDiary.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting those values `dttime`, `info` and `Topic` to the corresponding text views on each iteration of your for loop. So you are ending up having a single element, the last element set to the `TextView`. To solve this, you have to choices, one would be to **[append](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#append)** those value to the text viws or a more elegant way, would be to use a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` and an adapter. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `ListView` using and `ArrayAdapter` and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Would you please explain more of Appending Text View? I have done some surfing. i could not find a proper example

Comment: You can take a look here.

Comment: Yes, it pulls all the data in a single TextView. But again a problem, when you click an id from the list view, it should take just one entry. rather this displays the whole entry for every tap of the list.

Comment: In this case you need to use the second part of my answer. You cannot achieve this using append method.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply. i am on it.

Comment: this is the error i get from logcat :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.daunte_pc.anique.HomeThreeViewDiary$1.onDataChange(HomeThreeViewDiary.java:106)

and the line is: 
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the code you've written.