# RecyclerView not displaying data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Code

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fetchResults();
}

private void fetchResults() {
    mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(id).child("Quiz").child("Results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot resultSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String user = resultSnapshot.getKey();
                String score = resultSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Results results = new Results(user, score);
                resultsList.add(results);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

Saving the data

```
 String name = RecieversName;
                HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put("Name", name);
                userMap.put("Score", String.valueOf(mScore));
                mRef.child("Users").child(RecieversId).child("Quiz").child("Results").child(UID).setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(TakingQuiz.this, TakingQuizDone.class);
                            intent.putExtra("RecieversId",RecieversId);
                            intent.putExtra("Score", mScore.toString());
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Database structure - https://ibb.co/dJ6PdJ

If it the name was constant and the value was variable I could have solved it by myself I guess but here the name is set by the name of the user and value the score... I have never worked this type in firebase database so unsure... when I run the above code it doesn't display anything just a blank screen

Comment: did you knew about firebase UI ? you can archieve this just by using firebaseRecyclerAdapter, take a look at it here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database

Comment: Please post your adapter code

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to fetch all data from firebase and apply the check at the last item count and set the data into Adapter.
Please refer below code for your reference.

```
int totalItem = 0;
private void fetchResults() {
    mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(id).child("Quiz").child("Results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
totalItem = dataSnapshot. getChildrenCount();
            for (DataSnapshot resultSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String user = resultSnapshot.getKey();
                String score = resultSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Results results = new Results(user, score);
                resultsList.add(results);
                if(totalItem == resultsList.size())
                {
                // set the data into Adapter
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```