# Search in data name Firebase listview android

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

**Hi please help!
i have listview and the data frome Firebase and i want to add search bar or searchView to get names Movies frome data firebase**

[This is my data in firabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvTV1.png)

Comment: When searching for a name
All data with the same name appear in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference query = mDatabase.child("Movies");
query.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = (String) messageSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
                Log.d("TAG", "name is :"+name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i don"t understand 
hwo can i do that 
sorry but i'm still beginner

Comment: you can log your data in `onDataChange`, please check my updated answer...    for showing data in list you have to set that

Comment: i don't have any idea how can i sett data Which has been brought in listview

Comment: you can follow some blog for that https://www.mytrendin.com/receive-data-firebase-display-recyclerview-android/

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to use a query that looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Movies").orderByChild("name").startAt(name).endAt(name + "\uf8ff");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where you can find people who can write code for you. You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer, and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: how can i sett the data Which has been brought in list https://a.top4top.net/p_922wxzoj1.png

Comment: That's correct, now get the data from the `DataSnapshot` object.

Comment: i don't have any idea how can i sett data Which has been brought in  listview

Comment: Take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)**.

Comment: What works? To display the data in the ListView, use the code specified in that answer, right?

Comment: Do you think that my answer and comments helped you?