# Android- Firebase data not showing in ArrayList

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve data from `Firebase` database. The top level node is messages and child nodes are author and message. After logging in, the chat messages are pulled from the database. `ChatActivity` calls the `ChatListAdapter` 
with the following code:-

```
    mAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(this, mDatabaseReference);
    mChatListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Here `mChatListView` is a `RecyclerView`. The adapter code is as following:-

```
    public class ChatListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> mSnapshotList;

    private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            mSnapshotList.add(dataSnapshot);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView authorName, body;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            authorName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);

        }
    }

    public ChatListAdapter(Activity activity, DatabaseReference ref) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mDatabaseReference = ref.child("messages");
        mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mListener);
        mSnapshotList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.chat_row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        InstantMessage message = getItem(position);
        String author = message.getAuthor();
        holder.authorName.setText(author);
        String msg = message.getMessage();
        holder.body.setText(msg);
    }

    public InstantMessage getItem(int i) {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = mSnapshotList.get(i);
        return snapshot.getValue(InstantMessage.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSnapshotList.size();
    }    
}
```

The ChatActivity is as follows:-

```
    public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mChatListView;    
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private ChatListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_chat);    

        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();           
        mChatListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(this, mDatabaseReference);
        mChatListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAdapter.cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your full code including your activity.

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari  full code including activity has been added.

Comment: add this line `mSnapshotList = new ArrayList<>();` inside onChildAdded before `mSnapshotList.add(dataSnapshot);`

Comment: @PeterHaddad   that line is already present in ChatListAdapter constructor.

Comment: @John If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)** is how you can use an `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: @AlexMamo   thank you. I will definitely check. But I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @John Try do use one of the example above, which is more apropiate for you and then make the difference.

Comment: @AlexMamo  For that, do I need FirebaseUI  dependency ?

Comment: @John Yes, take a look [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

Comment: @AlexMamo  it has worked sir !! Many many thanks. I want to accept your answer :-)

Comment: You're welcome! I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: literally all u had to do was put this `mSnapshotList = new ArrayList<>();` inside onChildAdded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can solve thos problem. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)** is how you can use an `ArrayAdapter`.

But note, in order to use those answers you need to add Firebase-UI dependency. See [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

Add Data in array list through Map, Example shoving the detail

Following method to fetch Data from Firebase :

```
public void getUsers(){
    final ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();
    DatabaseReference q1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    q1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            collectiouser((Map<String,Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(ChatPage.this,FriendsProfile.class);
            i.putExtra("receiver",receiver);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Add Data into List :

```
private void collectiouser(Map<String, Object> value) {
    ArrayList<String> user=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : value.entrySet()){
        Map singleuser=(Map)entry.getValue();
        String u=entry.getKey();
        String s=singleuser.toString();
        user.add(u); // Add Data into List
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not initializing the mSnapshotList, you need to initialize your array list like `private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> mSnapshotList=new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I did it inside the ChatListAdapter constructor.

Comment: in this case write `mAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(this, mDatabaseReference);
    mChatListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` code in onDatachange event of firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Insight> insightList = new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseData mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(your reference key);
mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         insightList.clear();
         for (DataSnapshot noteSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren(){
               Insight note = noteSnapshot.getValue(Insight.class);
               insightList.add(note);
         }
         // pass list in recyclerview
       }
           @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```