# Android Firebase Listview retrieve data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjS7D.png)
I am working on android using Firebase Database. I want to retrieve the data on a listview of firebase database. I am providing the code and picture of which data have to retrieve.

Model Class:

```
public class FoodItemclass {

private String ItemName;
private String price;


private int count;

public FoodItemclass()
{}
public FoodItemclass(String itemane,String itemprice,int con)
{
    ItemName = itemane;
    price =itemprice;
    count = con;
}

public String getmItemName() {
    return ItemName;
}

public void setmItemName(String mItemName) {
    this.ItemName = mItemName;
}

public String getmItemPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setmItemPrice(String mItemPrice) {
    this.price = mItemPrice;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
```

}

Adapter Class:

```
public class FoodItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FoodItemclass> {


public FoodItemAdapter(Activity context, List<FoodItemclass> arrayList)
{
    super(context,0,arrayList);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
   View ListItemView = convertView;

   if(ListItemView == null)
   {
       ListItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
   }
     FoodItemclass foodItemclass = getItem(position);

       TextView itename = ListItemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemnameId);
       itename.setText(foodItemclass.getmItemName());

       TextView itemprice = ListItemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemPriceId);
       itemprice.setText(foodItemclass.getmItemPrice());

   return ListItemView;
}
```

}

Main Class:
    public class RiceCategory extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FoodItemAdapter mFoodAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rice_category);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UpdatedMenu").child("Noodles & Rice");
    final List<FoodItemclass> foodItemclasses = new ArrayList<>();
    mFoodAdapter =new FoodItemAdapter(this,foodItemclasses);
    ListView mListview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview) ;
    mListview.setAdapter(mFoodAdapter);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("Rice");
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
         public void onChildAdded( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,  String s) {
                 FoodItemclass food = dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodItemclass.class);
                 foodItemclasses.add(food);
                 mFoodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,  String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,  String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I am really stuck in it I tried different methods but I didn't get any result so I posted here to know from you guys if you find any mistake in the code so please post on comments and make it correct. I'll be very thankful to you

Comment: What is wrong when you are using this code? Do you have an error?

Comment: No, I can't get the value of item name and price on the text view mentioned in model class :(

Comment: Not even your price isn't displayed? Have you seen my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)**?

Comment: I checked brother but when I put the value price in a list it gives me error I don't know why

Comment: It gives you an error which is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the item layout to the array adapter constructor. But you were sending it as 0

```
public FoodItemAdapter(Activity context, List<FoodItemclass> arrayList)
{
    super(context,0,arrayList);
}
```

Change the **0** to **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** or some custom view xml

Comment: I tried this but I've two text field in custom list view and when I run the app it doesn't show any data in that text field i.e the price and item name. could you elaborate more as it is not working Viswanath Kumar Sandu?

Comment: pass R.layout.list_item instead of 0 in super method, 

and then remove    
`if(ListItemView == null) 
   {
       ListItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
   }`    
 from getView() method

IT should work

Comment: The Application start crashing brother :(

Comment: share the crash report

Comment: It's restarting

Comment: There are no errors brother but it's just restarting time by time

Comment: There might be something else which is breaking. No code from the here can cause restart.

Comment: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

Comment: at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)

Comment: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7102)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)

Comment: There are much more on LogCat

Comment: This is something related to firebase.

Comment: What should I do then brother?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change your parent child from ex. Noodle & Rice to Noodle_&_Rice?

Comment: because i think that maybe it's cause by name of children.