# firebase gets data too many times

Tags: android, firebase

I used recyclerview, arraylist, and firebase to get and show data, but data is added to the list too many times..

This is my code

```
database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef=database.getReference("SETS");

    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot==null) return;
            for(DataSnapshot userSanpshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                if(userSanpshot.child("DETAIL").getValue()==null) break;
               single.Detail=userSanpshot.child("DETAIL").getValue().toString();
                /~/
               list.add(single);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    adapter.setItems(list);
```

and this is my code when I send data to firebase

```
Button sharebut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.usersend);
    sharebut.setOnClickListener(
            new FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mDatabase.child("SETS").child(userId).child("DETAIL").setValue(detailText.getText().toString());
                    /~/
                    finish();
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Comment: add list.clear(); as the first line inside onDataChange method

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)** out.

Comment: @JinsonPaul Thank you, it works. But when I restart the app, the list changes; all data changes to the latest data.

Comment: because addValueEventListener always etches the latest data, or the all data stored in node you specified

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this method

```
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // do here your work
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // handle error here
  }
});
```

Comment: I changed and I think the number of data is same as in firebase.. but data are all same(the latest data)