# Firebase display data from multiple references in a single RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 reference points. Services and servicetypes. Now as you can see servicetypes has a foreign key for each service.
see below image:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAiZu.png)

Now I want to set value listener in both points and read data and display them in a RecyclerView. Each service has multiple service types.

I have done it like this

```
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference(getString(R.string.services));
    Query userQuery=myRef.child(FireBaseUtils.getFirebaseId());
    userQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<Map<String,String>> temp=new ArrayList<>();

     for(DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
     {

      final Service  s=d.getValue(Service.class);
       String id=d.getKey();
         Log.d("TEST", ": "+id);

         serviceTypesReference=database.getReference(getString(R.string.servicetypes)).child(id);
         serviceTypesReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //services.clear();
                 ArrayList<ServiceType> serviceTypes=new ArrayList<>();
                 Service tempService=new Service(s.getName());
                 for(DataSnapshot dd:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                 {
                     ServiceType st= dd.getValue(ServiceType.class);
                     Log.d("TEST", "typename: "+st.getName());
                     serviceTypes.add(st);
                 }
                 tempService.setServiceTypeArrayList(serviceTypes);

                 services.add(tempService);
                 serviceAdapter=new ServiceAdapter(services);
                 servicesRecyclerView.setAdapter(serviceAdapter);
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });

             }            }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here a service object contains a name and an ArrayList containing all service types it includes.
List of these service objects is passed to the adapter of the RecyclerView.

Now, this does the job but is very inefficient and maybe can cause bugs I don't see right now.
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you are trying to display all `servicetypes` of each `service` or only the `servicetypes` of a single service like `Tiffin`?

Comment: I am tring to display all services along with the number of servicetypes inside them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am tring to display all services along with the number of servicetypes inside them

To solve this, you should query your database twice. Assuming that `getString(R.string.services)` returns `service`, `getString(R.string.servicetypes)` returns `servicetypes` and `FireBaseUtils.getFirebaseId()` holds that id `kPBgLQo9WrbhJ01eReOOWbox1Uy1`, please the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("services").child("kPBgLQo9WrbhJ01eReOOWbox1Uy1");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

            DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.child("servicetypes").child(key);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    Log.d(TAG, name + "(" + count + ")");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                }
            };
            keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

I have hardcoded the name of the nodes to see it more clearly. The result in your logcat will be:

```
Tiffin(3)
Milk(x)
//And so on
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't try it yet, I will check now and update you :)

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, Actually logging gives correct output here. I need to add those outputs into an ArrayList and pass them to an adapter. The only place where I can do it is inside the eventListener right?
after this line:
     Log.d(TAG, name + "(" + count + ")");
and thanks for reminding me about errors :D

Comment: Good to hear that it gives the correct output :) Yes, you should do that inside the callback. Please take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623379/5246885)**.

Comment: The solution is fine but how is the data going into recycler view you have not shown that

Comment: @DragonFire I have showed but in another answer. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384849/5246885)** out.