# Unable to get list of cities from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get list of cities from Firebase and showing in spinner. But I am getting following error below:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Models.FirebaseCityModel

Database structure:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
 dRef.child("Cities").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            List<FirebaseCityModel> cities = new ArrayList<>();

            for(DataSnapshot areaSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                FirebaseCityModel areaName = areaSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseCityModel.class);
                cities.add(areaName);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.spinner_city,
                    R.id.locaions,list);

            chooseLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to fetch locations",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,TastyToast.ERROR).show();
        }
    });
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: your problem is here : `areaSnapshot.child("city").getValue(FirebaseCityModel.class)` you need to convert that to your model

Comment: @Alex added database structure screenshot.

Comment: Is exactly what I was thinking about. Just use my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem in code is that are making an extra `.child()` call. So to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
FirebaseCityModel areaName = areaSnapshot.child("city").getValue(FirebaseCityModel.class);
```

to

```
FirebaseCityModel areaName = areaSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseCityModel.class);
```

Comment: When I am Logging output using your solution I am getting something like this ``Models.FirebaseCityModel@f03007d`` and ``Models.FirebaseCityModel@c1b7b72``.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I cannot be much of a help. Beside that, before implementing that, have you tried my solution above?

Comment: I have updated my code with your code please see my post.

Comment: Looks good. Now, provide me the entire error message and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: There is no error but showing something like this in log cat ``Models.FirebaseCityModel@c2d88fa`` and ``Models.FirebaseCityModel@a7baeab``.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. In that case, please override `toString()` method in your `FirebaseCityModel` class to return your `city` string, as showed also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview). This is the simplest solution. Does it work now? Th

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onDataChange()` change ur code to -

```
FirebaseCityModel areaName = areaSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseCityModel.class);
```