# Trying to retrieve data from Firebase and get this error: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[The database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX5sW.png)

I build an application and I'm trying to retrieve user info from Firebase. After the registration form, I have a new activity where the users need to write their personal info and that information is stored in firebase. Then, in my navigation drawer, I have an activity, called "AccountActivity", where the user cand see their personal info saved into the database. I tried to write some code in order to do this, but when I try to access the AccountActivity, it is empty..doesn't retrieve user info from firebase and I get this error:

> SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero-length

Do you know what is wrong and what can I do in order to fix it?

This is the data I have in firebase, in JSON format, so the database is not empty:

```
  "User" : {
    "cgIW3VyfDONZjgA0r8LfGNr1zEO2" : {
      "age" : "30",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "height" : "170",
      "username" : "Alex",
      "weight" : "80"
    },
    "gLMP5YpLheQBWGxfyT5xcfOI9ii1" : {
      "age" : "28",
      "height" : "155",
      "username" : "Ana",
      "weight" : "60"
    }
  }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String age;
    public String weight;
    public String height;
    public String gender;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String username, String age, String weight, String height, String gender){

        this.username = username;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.gender = gender;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

AccountActivity:

```
public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseUser user;
    List<String> itemList;
    String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

        myListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userId = user.getUid();
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

         databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        userRef = databaseReference.child("User");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);

                    itemList.add(user.getUsername());
                    itemList.add(user.getAge());
                    itemList.add(user.getWeight());
                    itemList.add(user.getHeight());
                    itemList.add(user.getGender());
                }
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AccountActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
                myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

activity_account.xml:

```
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="263dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:text="@string/account_informations"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:fontFamily="@font/alex_brush"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsernameDb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="178dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="178dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="175dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="175dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="539dp"
        android:text="@string/textviewUsernameDb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAgeDb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="173dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="173dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="468dp"
        android:text="@string/textviewAgeDb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUsernameDb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWeightDb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="173dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="173dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="402dp"
        android:text="@string/textviewWeightDb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAgeDb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeightDb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="181dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="181dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="171dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="171dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="325dp"
        android:text="@string/textviewHeightDb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvWeightDb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGenderDb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="182dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="171dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="171dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="252dp"
        android:text="@string/textviewGenderDb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvHeightDb" />
```

In XML file, I put some text views, but with no text, just black space, and in string.xml I have something like this for each TextView form activity_account.xml:
`<string name="textviewGenderDb">" "</string>`

So my questions are: I didn't something wrong in the XML file, or the code is written is wrong? I don't know where is the problem and why I get this error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did something wrong in the XML file, or the code is written wrong?

There are three main problems.

1. The fields in your `User` class are public. If you want to use getters and setters, make all of them `private`.
2. Your `databaseReference` points to the root of your database but users are added within the `User` node. So in order to get all users, a call to `.child("User")` should be added. So please check the following lines of code:

   ```
   DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
   DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("User");
   ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
               Log.d("TAG", user.getUsername());
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
       }
   };
   userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
   ```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Alex
Ana
```

Two thinks you should note. First, you can directly map a node from the database to a `User` object, without the need to create a new object and set the values. Second, the node should be more likely to be named `Users` or `users` and not simply `User`, because in that node exist multiple users and not a single one.

3. Because you are iterating on a node that contains multiple users, [you should use instead of TextView object a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview). In this way you can add each details in a row.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I made all the fields in my User class private, and now it retrieves me only the height of the user, without the other fields. It seems a little bit strange, because I implement the exact thing for the other fields.

Comment: I also tried your code and I will try to implement this with a ListView, maybe in this way it will show up all the fields stored in the database for the current user.

Comment: Please edit your question to also see a screenshot of your database, to be 100% sure.

Comment: Done. I added a screenshot of my database.

Comment: It's correct. It should work using a ListView. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I tried with a ListView and still have the same problem: only the height is showed up..

Comment: Edit your question with the changed code so I can take a look.

Comment: I edited the AccountActivity with the new code. I tried to implement this in two ways, but this is the final version, that retrieves me at least height. The first version of what I tried returned me into Logcot : ```empty item```, I don't know why.

Comment: Again, wrong reference. A call to `.child("User")` is mandatory. You are still creating an object of User class calling the constructor. Map it directly as in my answer. Get both lines `arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AccountActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
            myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);` out of the loop and tell me if it works.

Comment: Ok, I changed AccountActivity considering your advices (I edited the question with the code) and now it retrieves me the height of all the users and nothing more. I am new to android studion and maybe I can see some obvious errors in my code or I don't know what's the thing with this problem

Comment: You are using a `List<String>` in which you are adding all that `user.getUsername()`, `user.getAge()`, getWeight() etc. return. Your list should be of type `User`. So you need to add User object to the list. In the end, simply override toString() in your User class and display the desired data.

Comment: I made the list User type and override toString(), but is there something I should change at ```itemList.add(user.getUsername());``` etc and ```arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AccountActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);``` ? because I have errors here, and if I solve the errors for ```itemList.add(user.getUsername());``` I get error in User class

Comment: The ArrayAdapter should also be of type User and when you add object to the list, add like this: `itemList.add(user);`

Comment: Now it retrieves me ``` null null null *height* null```, so all the params are null, except height

Comment: I will try to see where is the problem, maybe try another method

Comment: Without seeing the changed code, I cannot be much of a help. We usually stick to one question at a time but knowing that you are new to this, it's fine. So I hope you solved this issue.