# How do I make a dynamic ListView that saves more than just text with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

so my plan is to make it possible for the user to fill out a form of a product(for example) that includes multiple data like :(date, name, id, image) and then have those products listed in a ListView, and have these saved on my Firebase...

I have no idea where to start as I'm a rookie in Android, I also struggled to find anything online...
If you guys could help me or even link me a video of someone doing that, it'd be much appreciated!

**THANKS A LOT!**

Comment: I think this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)** might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of ListView

for that case you need a custom adapter

You can visit this [Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)