# How to refer sub child in realtime firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobile

I am going to find student attendance by matching the registration number stored in realtime database. I am trying hard to get the student's registration no and the date when student visited school.

[image: Here is my database picture and I want to get the date and registration number both and than display them in my view]

```
final FirebaseDatabase databs= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference p = databs.getReference("StudentAttend");
Query q= p.child("reg_no").orderByChild("date").equalTo(Parent_HomePage.childR)
```

Here is my query to fetch them. But the issue is that registration number and date have no names in database, they are keys. Kindly help me to fetch these attributes from database. Secondly kindly share Data snapshot code because my view doesn't show anything.

Thanks

Comment: What do you know about the student? The ID or Date or something?

Comment: Under "StudentAttend" I cannot see any "reg_no" and also no "date" property. Is it the right schema?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes this is the issue. 14-03-2021 is date and 165 is reg_no. There are not any name of these attributes. I don't came to know how I will approach them.

Comment: So what exactly would you like to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo Basically In my application Parent is able to check child's attendance. Here child attendance is saved. Whenever parent will check than all the dates when 165 attended the school will be displayed to parent.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't really understand. What is the exact data you want to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo You simply help me to write query to get the dates (14-03-2021) and the reg_no (165) from firebase to my listview

Comment: What would you like to display in a row in the LiswtView?

Comment: @AlexMamo List of Dates where 165 found.

Comment: What do you mean by "List of Dates where 165 found"?

Comment: @AlexMamo Kindly focus on firebase picture. I want to show dates in my list view whose child is 165.

Comment: I think I got it. I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

To get a key from realtime database you use getKey(). But i have to say you have to structure your data better. Also your query won't work as dates come before reg no. And ordering by date as shown will lead to issues for example 03-03-2021 will come before 20-02-2021.

```
       final FirebaseDatabase databs= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       DatabaseReference p = databs.getReference("StudentAttend");

       p.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dns) {
               for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dns.getChildren()) {
                   String key = dns.getKey(); //this will get the date
                   //to get the student number within a date use above key
                   p.child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dns) {
                             for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dns.getChildren()) {
                                 String key = dns.getKey(); //this will get the reg_no
                                 //get pick and drop here

                    }
              }}}
                        
         }
```

To query data when you have a date

```
           final FirebaseDatabase databs= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
           DatabaseReference p = databs.getReference("StudentAttend").child(date_you_have); //then add listener here
```

If you don't have a date but have a reg no, follow above code to get the date key, then run query in there with

```
p.child(key).child(regnoyouhvae);
```

But i suggest you go over documentation again and read some articles on structuring your data, queries and more.

Comment: Dates come before reg_no because every student attendance is saved relative to the dates. On which date, which students were present.

Answer (score 1):

According to your last comment:

> I want to show dates in my ListView whose child is 165.

To display the keys (dates) if the DataSnapshot object contains a child called "165", please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference studentAttendRef = rootRef.child("StudentAttend");
studentAttendRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                if (ds.child("165").exists()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", ds.getKey());
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
14-03-2021
15-04-2021
```

To be able to display these dates in a ListView, please see my answer from the following post:

- [Showing Firebase data in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622480/showing-firebase-data-in-listview)

Comment: Yes you got it.  Now I want to display dates regardless of reg_no. It may be 165 or 206 according to user input.

Comment: Simply pass a variable that can hold the value that you need. Something like "ds.child(numberYouNeed)" and **not** a hardcoded value, right?

Comment: Ok, Thanks Alot

Comment: I typed the above code and .get() is not accepted. It shows error on .get() `studentAttendRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>()`

Comment: Most likely you don't have the latest version of the Firebase Realtime Database. Update it and tell me if it works.